# Бот discord не отвечает на команду

Tags: python, discord

подскажите как решить данную проблему? При запуске бота должен возращать написанные сообщения, но не возращает:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Бот запущен')
    

@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

Comment: Код следует вставлять текстом

Comment: исправил картинку на текст

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно вы забыли, указать токен и запуск бота? Так же я рекомендую поменять client в @client.event на @bot.event.
Используйте команду как !foo (сообщение) и бот вернет сообщение.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
token = 'Здесь ваш токен' 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')




@bot.event #поменяйте на bot
async def on_ready():
    print('Бот запущен')


@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

bot.run(token)
```